# Subjectivity and objectivity detection

Tags: nlp

I am trying to separate subjective and objective sentences from eachother, I tried to find some good research papers in this area but all of the work is in sentiment analysis and I could not find any good paper just focusing on subjectivity and objectivity of the text... So now my question is how should I interpret interpret subjective and objective text? Is it possible to have a subjective sentence which is neutral in terms of sentiment? or when I say "I went to school", is it subjective or objective(I assume it is subjective since it is not about general fact)?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there are a lot of works devoted to subjectivity detection (as opposed to polarity detection; both tasks - SD and PD - are subtasks of sentiment analysis), see for example [google scholar](https://scholar.google.ru/scholar?q=subjectivity%20detection%20neutral%20objective&btnG=&hl=ru&as_sdt=0%2C5) or start from [classic](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~pb/cs626-449-2009/prev-years-other-things-nlp/sentiment-analysis-opinion-mining-pang-lee-omsa-published.pdf) (see sections 1.5 and 4.1.2)

> Pang, B., & Lee, L. (2008). Opinion mining and sentiment analysis.
>   Foundations and trends in information retrieval, 2(1-2), 1-135.

Citing this work, 
"Synonyms: opinion, view, belief, conviction, persuasion, sentiment mean a judgment one holds as true.

- opinion implies a conclusion thought out yet open to dispute (each
  expert seemed to have a different opinion).
- view suggests a subjective opinion (very assertive in stating his
  views).
- belief implies often deliberate acceptance and intellectual assent
  (a ﬁrm belief in her party’s platform).
- conviction applies to a ﬁrmly and seriously held belief (the
  conviction that animal life is as sacred as human).
- persuasion suggests a belief grounded on assurance (as by evidence)
  of its truth (was of the persuasion that everything changes).
- sentiment suggests a settled opinion reﬂective of one’s feelings (her
  feminist sentiments are well-known)."

"In 1994, Wiebe [312] (...) centered the idea of subjectivity around that of private states, deﬁned by Quirk et al. [246] as states that are not open to objective observation or veriﬁcation"

However, from my point of view, your example contradicts to common notion of subjective/objective texts: almost all would classify "I went to school" as objective, because it contains no opinion (or other synonyms from the list above).

Your motivation "it is not about general fact" lacks definition of 'general fact'. And if you really want to distinguish general facts from others, then most probably it has no relation to sentiment analysis and, particularly, subjectivity detection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so when we say opinion mining and sentiment analysis from your definition I assume that is exactly the same as subjectivity and objectivity so what is the point of separating these definitions ? let me put another way, is there an example that is subjective but does not have negative or positive opinion ?

Comment: From the same article, "Classifying a piece of text as expressing a neutral opinion (giving it a mid-point score) for rating inference does not equal classifying that piece of text as objective (lack of opinion): one can have a strong opinion that something is “mediocre” or “so-so”"
However, "the label “neutral” is sometimes used as a label for the objective class (“lack of opinion”) in the literature", but it is not common.

Comment: if so, can you give an example of the sentence which is subjective but neutral or vice versa?(I am a little bit confused)

Comment: "I went to school" or "My school is located in New York" - objective. 
"My school is mediocre" or "My school isn't bad and isn't good" - neutral.